# Kitematic Setup Error Docker

Tags: docker, windows-8.1, virtual-machine, boot2docker

I have this error on the Kitematic Setup

`ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\<redacted>\ca.pem'`

I've tried to retry the setup or delete the VM, but nothing works...

If someone have an idea ?

[image: error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that in some parts the VM is referred as "dev" whereas in some other parts (like the real physical path where the VM files are stored, etc) is referred as "default"

What I've done is just regenerate the certificates using the proper VM name and it now works!

Run from the Windows command line:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox>docker-machine regenerate-certs -f dev
Regenerating TLS certificates
Error: Host does not exist: dev

C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox>docker-machine regenerate-certs -f default
Regenerating TLS certificates

C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox>
```

And that will do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

It is related as a known issue at [Kitematic website](https://kitematic.com/docs/known-issues/). They suggest to keep retrying or to use the command line:

```
docker-machine rm -f dev
docker-machine create -d virtualbox dev
```

*PS: On my machine, Kitematic was using the name `default` instead of `dev`.*